# delete mapping from edmx

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In the edmx file I deleted some of the properties because I don't want to add them to the POCO object, but each time I get that kind of exception:

```
Error   1   Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 255:Column COMPANY.contact_phone_number in table COMPANY must be mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable.
```

Why do I need map those columns if they don't have default values and are not nullable??

Comment: I believe Microsoft explicitly states in the .edmx files that no changes should ever be made to it for the simple reason that the entity engine will generate over it. If you don't want certain properties in your entities than don't use generated entities. Use mapped pocos instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it.
I must map non-nullable fields without default value because when inserting there must be a value to the field!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand, you have a POCO class and then that same class also has a definition in the EDMX and you're specifying some properties in the POCO and some in the EDMX?

Comment: I got again and again exception which I can't understand its reason.